# Is there a bug in AssociatePairs?

Tags: bugs, packages

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

In **Version 10**, the `GeneralUtilities` package contain some useful functions. `AssociatePairs` is one of those functions included in the package and advertised to work as follows:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

?AssociatePairs
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Well, here is an input that matches a `List` of pairs:

```
lis = Table[{k, k^3}, {k, 2, 10}];
```

Now,

```
AssociatePairs[lis]
```

Gives the following error:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Well, the included `PairQ` function disagrees with this assertion:

```
AllTrue[lis, PairQ]
```

> True

So, is this a bug? Since I can't get any list of pairs to work with this function. I'm on **Windows 8.1**

Comment: Looks like a bug for me, why not to report to [Wolfram Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/)?

Comment: @m0nhawk, I need more people to confirm this behavior and on different operating systems.

Comment: confirm on Windows 8.1 (x64), will check on Linux in few hours.

Comment: @m0nhawk. Thanks

Comment: confirm on Win7 x64.

Comment: is `GeneralUtilities` supposed to be an `official` thing? or some kind of still-in-work package? If it is official, where to find official documentation about it? When I type http://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=GeneralUtilities I do not see it?

Comment: I'm getting the same on OSX 10.9.4

Comment: Confirmed for Ubuntu 14.04. Why they allow us to `Needs` this library without any popup with `this package is in developement`?

Comment: Error persists in 10.0.1.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I noticed too. Too bad, we'll have to wait for the next update.

Comment: @RunnyKine Or just patch the condition as I described. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Of course, I already use your patch :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using Simon Woods's `Spelunk` we see that the body of the function is:

```
Self : AssociatePairs[l_] := 
 Module[{r$}, 
  r$ = Which[! Quiet[TrueQ[MatrixQ[l, PairQ]]], Message[AssociatePairs::npairs, l];
    $FailRHS, True, HoldSequence[Associate @@ Transpose[l]]];
  ReleaseHoldSequence[r$] /; ! MatchQ[r$, $FailRHS | HoldSequence[$FailRHS]]
]
```

I draw your attention to:

```
TrueQ[MatrixQ[l, PairQ]]
```

Recalling the definition of [`MatrixQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixQ.html):

[image]

This means that the function is checking that:

1. `l` (input) is a matrix
2. *each element* passes `PairQ`

This is apparently illogical.

One could correct this with one of many other possible checks, simplest perhaps:

```
MatchQ[l, {{_, _} ..}]
```

Or to allow for `SparseArray` input, as may have been the motivation for `MatrixQ`:

```
MatchQ[Dimensions[l], {_, 2}] && MatrixQ[l]
```

Comment: That is an interesting condition! As an aside, every time I use `spelunk` I want to hug @SimonWoods

Comment: Yeah, the condition is clearly off. Hopefully it will be corrected when they finally add it as an internal function.

Comment: This is fixed, which is too late for 10.0.2, but will be present in 10.0.3

Comment: @Taliesin Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Didn't we go from 10.0.2 to 10.1?

Comment: @Sjoerd Right; even the developers assumed there would be a 10.0.3, then marketing got involved I suppose. ◔_◔

Answer (score 6):

This is an adjunct to @Mr.Wizard's answer: while I've fixed this for 10.0.3, anyone who wants to use this rather trivial function in the meantime can run `` SystemOpen["GeneralUtilitiesLoader`"] `` and then paste the following code at the end of that file:

```
Begin["GeneralUtilities`General`PackagePrivate`"]
AssociatePairs[l_] := Macros`ConditionalRHS[
    (MatrixQ[l] && Dimensions[l][[2]] == 2) || VectorQ[l, PairQ], {"npairs", l}, 
    AssociationThread @@ Transpose[l]];
End[];
```

P.S. What goodies does `Macros` contain? Only the intrepid spelunker will find out!