# List creation/manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to a create a list from `A = {{a}, {b}, {c}}` by taking each elements `n` times in the following form:

> ```
> B={{a},{a},{a},{b},{b},{b},{c},{c},{c}}
> ```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

[`ConstantArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConstantArray.html) is your friend.

```
Flatten[ConstantArray[#, 3] & /@ {{a}, {b}, {c}}, 1]
```

> ```
> {{a}, {a}, {a}, {b}, {b}, {b}, {c}, {c}, {c}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

My additions, duplicating the entire array first:

```
ConstantArray[A, 3] ~Flatten~ {2, 1}

Join @@ (ConstantArray[A, 3]\[Transpose])

Join @@ Thread @ ConstantArray[A, 3]

Sequence ~MapThread~ ConstantArray[A, 3]
```

### Benchmarks

Timings for all methods in the order they were posted, tested only for triplication on a packed array.

```
f1[array_] := 
 Composition[Flatten[#, 1] &, Replace[#, x_ :> ConstantArray[x, 3], 1] &][array]
f2[A_] := Flatten[ConstantArray[#, 3] & /@ A, 1]
f3[A_] := Flatten[A /. {x_} :> {{x}, {x}, {x}}, 1]
f4[A_] := Flatten[{#, #, #} & /@ A, 1]
f5[A_] := ConstantArray[A, 3] ~Flatten~ {2, 1}
f6[A_] := Join @@ (ConstantArray[A, 3]\[Transpose])
f7[A_] := Join @@ Thread @ ConstantArray[A, 3]
f8[A_] := Sequence ~MapThread~ ConstantArray[A, 3]
f[x_] := Sequence[x, x, x];
f9[A_] := f /@ A

gen = RandomInteger[99, {#, 1}] &;

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[
  {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9},
  gen, 2^Range[20], "IncludeFits" -> True
]
```

[image]

All methods have the same order of complexity but there is **a clear winner for speed:**

```
f5[A_] := ConstantArray[A, 3] ~Flatten~ {2, 1}
```

Running the tests again with unpackable data:

```
gen2 = "a" ~CharacterRange~ "z" ~RandomChoice~ {#, 1} &;

BenchmarkPlot[
  {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9},
  gen2, 2^Range[20], "IncludeFits" -> True
]
```

[image]

The winners are `f6`, `f7`, and `f5` in order, with `f6` and `f7` only slightly ahead of `f5` which does not justify their use given `f5`'s large margin of performance on packed data.

Comment: +1 for `Flatten`. BTW my MMA 10 could not generate `BenchmarkPlot`. All I got was [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JN6K9.png).

Comment: @seismatica Thanks for the vote.  Very strange error; I guess `BenchmarkPlot` has some bugs to work out.  The package is very new and [rough in spots.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54999/121)

Comment: Is this a built-in package or do I have to download it somewhere?

Comment: @seismatica It is built into version 10 and should be loaded by the line ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]``

Answer (score 4):

Here is an interesting approach:

We first define a helper function:

```
f[x_] := Sequence[x, x, x]
```

Then it's just a matter of mapping it on `A` to create `B`:

```
A = {{a}, {b}, {c}}; 

f /@ A
```

> {{a}, {a}, {a}, {b}, {b}, {b}, {c}, {c}, {c}}

We could also use a SubValues (or "operator form") definition for flexible replication:

```
g[n_][x_] := Sequence @@ ConstantArray[x, n];

g[3] /@ A
```

> {{a}, {a}, {a}, {b}, {b}, {b}, {c}, {c}, {c}}

```
MapAt[g[3], A, 2]
```

> {{a}, {b}, {b}, {b}, {c}}

Comment: Nice idea.  I added an extension assuming you wouldn't mind.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I don't mind your edits at all. Nice addition by the way. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this method proves to be one of the slower ones.  See my updated answer.  (The colors are hard to distinguish but `f9` is the line third from the top, meaning third slowest.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Oh well, we can't win all the time :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for variation, using replacement rules we have for small *n*:

```
Flatten[{{a}, {b}, {c}} /. {x_} :> {{x},{x},{x}}, 1]
```

and for large *n* :

```
Flatten[{{a}, {b}, {c}} /. {x_} :> Table[{x}, {3}], 1]
```

Comment: For large `n`, `Table` will slow down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Replace` with `levelspec = 1`

```
createArray[array_, n_] := Composition[
   Flatten[#, 1] &,
   Replace[#, x_ :> ConstantArray[x, n], 1] &
   ][array]
```

Check function:

```
createArray[{{a},{b},{c}}, 3]
(*{{a},{a},{a},{b},{b},{b},{c},{c},{c}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Different approaches (just for fun)

```
Join @@ (ComposeList[Table[# &, {2}], #] & /@ A)
Join @@ (Nest[Append[#, First@#] &, {#}, 2] & /@ A)
Join @@ (NestList[# &, #, 2] & /@ A)
Fold[Riffle[#1, A, {#2, -1, #2}] &, A, {2, 3}]
Join @@ MapThread[List, Table[A, {3}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Flatten[PadLeft[{#}, 3, {#}] & /@ {{a}, {b}, {c}}, 1]
```